# How to change default image of derived ToolStripButton?

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, windows-forms-designer, toolstripbutton

It seems like a simple task. Create a C# class that derives from ToolStripButton. The derived ToolStripButton should behave exactly the same as the parent class in the designer and the application, except that the default image should be different.

Surprisingly just changing the constructor is not sufficient:

```
public CustomToolStripButton()
{
    base.Image = (Image) new Bitmap(typeof(CustomToolStripButton), "CustomImage.bmp");
}
```

When the ToolStripButton is displayed in the designer, the original default image is shown. There must be a simple solution. What could it be?

Answer (score 0):

i used the same code for this... i am able to see the new image ..

please comment the adding image to toolStripButton intialization in InitializeComponent of form

this is the code...

```
//this.toolStripButton1.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image) (resources.GetObject("toolStripButton1.Image")));
```

Comment: The problem with this is you need to manually edit the form's designer every time you make a change to the form. I'm looking for the derived ToolStripButton to behave the same as its parent without manually editing auto-generated code.